# How to solve encoding error for a Huffman Program in Java?

Tags: java, huffman-code

So I have been stuck on finishing this Huffman program and need help to finish the code method.

What I need to do is use recursion to traverse the huffTree and build a binary string for each stored char. It walks until it finds a leaf, adding "0" to the binaryCode string every time it has to turn left, or "1" every time it has to turn right. When it encounters a leaf, it calculates the codeTable index of the char stored there by subtracting 65 from it. Then it stores the binaryCode string in the codeTable at that index.

How my prof told me to implement it:

Implement:

If the Node's char is '+', it's not a leaf. Call this method recursively to walk this Node's left child, then right child. Add an appropriate 0 or 1 to the String that is passed to each recursive call.

If the Node's char is anything else, it's a char stored in a leaf. Calculate its index in the codeTable by subtracting 65, then store the binaryCode String there. This is the base case, so you need to do one more thing to terminate the call and pass control back to higher-level calls.

Here is what I wrote:

```
private void makeCodeTable (Node nd, String binaryCode){
   if (nd.leftChild != null && nd.rightChild != null){
      makeCodeTable(nd.leftChild, binaryCode + "0");
      makeCodeTable(nd.rightChild, binaryCode + "1");
  }else if (nd.leftChild == null && nd.rightChild == null) {
         int index = (int)nd.ch - 65;
         codeTable[index] = binaryCode;
   }
}
```

when I run my code and try to code the message I get an error:

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -64 out of bounds for length 28`

but I am unable to figure out what is wrong with it.

The main file to run:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
      Huffman huff = null;
      int value;
      String str;

      while(true){
         System.out.print("Enter first letter of ");
         System.out.print("enter, show, code, or decode: ");
         int choice = getChar();
         switch(choice){
            case 'e':
               System.out.println(
                  "Enter text lines, terminate with $");
               str = getText();
               huff = new Huffman(str);
               break;
            case 's':
               huff.displayTree();
               break;
            case 'c':
               huff.code();
               break;
            case 'd':
               huff.decode();
               break;
            default:
               System.out.print("Invalid entry\n");
            }  // end switch
         }  // end while
      }  // end main()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public static String getString() throws IOException{
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String s = br.readLine();
      return s;
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public static String getText() throws IOException {
      String outStr="", str = "";
      while(true){
         str = getString();
         if( str.equals("$") )
            return outStr;
         outStr = outStr + str + "\n";
         }
      }  // end getText()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public static char getChar() throws IOException {
      String s = getString();
      return s.charAt(0);
      }
//-------------------------------------------------------------
   public static int getInt() throws IOException{
      String s = getString();
      return Integer.parseInt(s);
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class HuffmanApp
```

The file where I am working on:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.BitSet;

public class Huffman {
   private PQ theQueue;
   private String inString;        // input from user
   private int strlen;
   private String capsString;      // converted to all caps
   private Tree[] treeArray;
   private Tree huffTree;          // Huffman tree
   private int freqTable[];        // letter frequencies
   private int alphabetSize;       // size of frequency table
   private String codeTable[];     // code for each letter
   private String codedMsg;        // binary string
   private String decodedMsg;      // back to original msg
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   Huffman(String s){
      inString = s;
      strlen = inString.length();
      alphabetSize = 28;                 // 26 letters, cr, lf
      theQueue = new PQ(alphabetSize); // make the queue
      capsString = "";
      codeTable = new String[alphabetSize];   // make code table
      makeFreqTable();          // construct frequency table
      queueTrees();             // put one-node trees in queue
      makeHuffTree();           // construct Huffman tree
      }  // end constructor
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void displayTree() {
      if(huffTree != null)
         huffTree.display();
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
  private void makeFreqTable(){
      freqTable = new int[alphabetSize];
      int temp;
 
      for(int j=0; j<strlen; j++){
          // of user's input msg
         char ch = inString.charAt(j);
         if(ch>96 && ch<123){
            temp = (int)ch - 32;         // convert to upper
            ch = (char)temp;             //    (65-90)
            }
         if(ch==32)                      // space becomes 91
            ch = 91;
         else if(ch==10)                 // linefeed becomes 92
            ch = 92;
         else if(ch<65 || ch>92)         // if not uppercase
            continue;                    // letter, ignore it
         capsString = capsString + ch;   // add to caps string
         int index = (int)ch - 65;       // convert to 0 to 27
         freqTable[index]++;             // keep count in
         }  // end for                   //    frequency table
      System.out.println(capsString);    // all-caps string
      for(int j=0; j<28; j++)            // row of characters
         System.out.print( (char)(j+65) + " ");
      System.out.println("");
      for(int j=0; j<28; j++)            // row of frequencies
         System.out.print(freqTable[j] + " ");
      System.out.println("");
      }  // end makeFreqTable()
  
// -------------------------------------------------------------
// TODO: IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD!
//--------------------------------------------------------------
  
   private void queueTrees() {
       // Description:
       // This method goes through the frequency table, creates a one-Node tree
       // for each char that appears in the original message, and inserts that tree into the PQ.
       // The insert method of the PQ stores in order of increasing frequency (so lowest frequency
       // is at the top of the queue).
       // Implement:
       // Check frequency of char. If 0, don't add it to the PQ (we don't need it). Skip to next char.
       // Make a Node with the char and its frequency (which you get from the frequency table
       // ** NOTE **: In doing this, you need to add 65 to each char to make it the correct character!
       // This is because the index of this char in the frequency table has had 65 subtracted from it
       // in the makeFreqTable method in order to give it an index of 0-27.
       // Insert this Node into the PQ (you'll have to take one additional step to do this:
       // study the PQ insert method carefully to see what that step is.)

       for (int i = 0; i < freqTable.length; i++) {
           if (freqTable[i] != 0) {
               Tree tree = new Tree(new Node((char)freqTable[i], (char)(i+65)));
               theQueue.insert(tree);
           }
       }// end queueTrees()

   }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
// TODO: IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD!
//--------------------------------------------------------------
       private void makeHuffTree () {
           while (theQueue.getSize() > 1) {

               // Description:
               // This method combines all the trees in the PQ in the correct order of increasing frequency
               // to make a single tree, the huffTree, that can be walked to generate a unique Huffman code
               // for each char.


               // Implement:
               // Get the trees with the smallest frequencies, storing them in a left and right child

               // Add their frequencies and store it in a new Node whose char is '+'
               // (This marks the node as a junction rather than a leaf)

               // Make a tree from this Node and attach the trees you got above as its children

               // Reinsert this tree into the PQ.

               Tree left = theQueue.remove();
               Tree right = theQueue.remove();
               Node newNode = new Node('+', left.root.freq + right.root.freq);
               Tree newTree = new Tree(newNode);
               newTree.root.leftChild = left.root;
               newTree.root.rightChild = right.root;
               theQueue.insert(newTree);

               /*
               for (int i = 1; i < alphabetSize; i++) {
                   Tree a = theQueue.remove();
                   int freq1 = a.getFreq();
                   Tree b = theQueue.remove();
                   int freq2 = b.getFreq();
                   int newfreq = freq1 + freq2;
                   Node newNode = new Node(' ', newfreq);
                   Tree c = new Tree(newNode);
                   theQueue.insert(c);
               }

                */
           }

           huffTree = theQueue.remove();      // final tree
       }  // end makeHuffTree()

// -------------------------------------------------------------
// TODO: IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD!
//--------------------------------------------------------------

       private void makeCodeTable (Node nd, String binaryCode){
           // Description:
           // This method uses recursion to traverse the huffTree and build a binary string
           // for each stored char. It walks until it finds a leaf, adding "0" to the binaryCode string
           // every time it has to turn left, or "1" every time it has to turn right.
           // When it encounters a leaf, it calculates the codeTable index of the char stored there
           // by subtracting 65 from it. Then it stores the binaryCode string in the codeTable at that index.
           // Implement:
           // If the Node's char is '+', it's not a leaf. Call this method recursively to walk
           // this Node's left child, then right child. Add an appropriate 0 or 1 to the String that is passed
           // to each recursive call.
           // If the Node's char is anything else, it's a char stored in a leaf. Calculate its index
           // in the codeTable by subtracting 65, then store the binaryCode String there.
           // This is the base case, so you need to do one more thing to terminate the call and pass
           // control back to higher-level calls.
           /*
           if (nd == null) return;

           if (nd.leftChild != null && nd.rightChild != null) {
               if (binaryCode.length() > 0) {
                   codeTable[toIndex(nd.ch)] = binaryCode.toString();
               } else {
                   codeTable[toIndex(nd.ch)] = "0";
               }
           } else {
               makeCodeTable(nd.leftChild, binaryCode + "0");
               makeCodeTable(nd.rightChild, binaryCode + "1");
           }*/
           if(nd.leftChild == null && nd.rightChild == null){
               codeTable[(int)nd.ch - 65] = binaryCode;
           }else if(nd.leftChild != null){
               makeCodeTable(nd.leftChild, binaryCode + "0");
           }else {
               makeCodeTable(nd.rightChild, binaryCode + "1");
           }
       }  // end makeCodeTable()

// -------------------------------------------------------------
// TODO: IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD!
//--------------------------------------------------------------

       public void code () {

           // Description:
           // This method first creates a codeTable using the makeCodeTable method, which walks
           // the huffTree to generate a unique Huffman Code for each char in the original message.
           // Then it produces a coded message (a string of 0s and 1s) by looking up each char
           // in the original message in the codeTable and adding its Huffman Code to the coded string.


           // Implement:
           // Create the codeTable by calling makeCodeTable with the appropriate parameters.
           // Initialize codedMsg to an empty string.
           // Walk through capsString. For each char in capsString, subtract 65 to get its codeTable index,
           // then look up that char's Huffman Code in codeTable. Add this Huffman Code to codedMsg.


           makeCodeTable(huffTree.root, "");
           /*for (int j = 0; j < alphabetSize; j++) {
               if (codeTable[j] == null) {
                   continue;
               }
               char ch = (char) (j + 65);
               System.out.println(ch + " " + codeTable[j]);
           }*/
           codedMsg = "";
           int index = 0;
           for (int j = 0; j < capsString.length(); j++) {
               index = (int) capsString.charAt(j) - 65;
           }
           codedMsg = codedMsg + codeTable[index];
           System.out.println("Coded msg:\n" + codedMsg);
       }  // end code()

// -------------------------------------------------------------
// TODO: IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD!
//--------------------------------------------------------------

       public void decode () {

           // Description:
           // This method uses the huffTree to walk the coded message until it encounters a leaf,
           // then adds the char in that leaf to the decoded message.


           // Implement:
           // Initialize decodedMsg to an empty string.
           // Move through the entire codedMsg one 0 or 1 at a time. Use each 0 or 1 to walk down the
           // huffTree from its root until the current Node doesn't contain '+' as its char.
           // (This means you've found a leaf with an actual char.)
           // Pass this leaf Node to the helper function getChar, which will attach the right
           // char to decodedMsg for you.
           // Repeat until the entire codedMsg has been traversed.


           decodedMsg = "";
           Node nd = huffTree.root;
           for (int i = 0; i < codedMsg.length(); i++) {
               if (codedMsg.charAt(i) == '0') {
                   nd = nd.leftChild;
               } else {
                   nd = nd.rightChild;
               }
               if (nd.leftChild == null && nd.rightChild == null) {
                   decodedMsg = decodedMsg + nd.ch;
                   nd = huffTree.root;
               }
           }
           System.out.println("Decoded msg:\n" + decodedMsg);
       }  // end decode()

       // helper function to attach readable chars to decoded message
       public void getChar (Node nd){

           char add;

           if (nd.ch == 91)
               add = ' ';
           else if (nd.ch == 92)
               add = '\n';
           else
               add = nd.ch;

           decodedMsg = decodedMsg + add;
       } // end getChar

       // this prints the codeTable for inspection
       public void displayCodeTable () {
           for (int j = 0; j < alphabetSize; j++) {
               if (codeTable[j] == null)
                   continue;
               char ch = (char) (j + 65);
               System.out.println(ch + " " + codeTable[j]);
           }
       } // end displayCodeTable

       private int toIndex ( char c){
           return ((int) c) - 65;
       }
// -------------------------------------------------------------// end class Huffman
   }
```

Node.java

```
public class Node {
    
// FIELDS ------------------------------------------------------
   public char ch;                // letter
   public int freq;               // instances of this letter
   public Node leftChild;         // this node's left child
   public Node rightChild;        // this node's right child

// CONSTRUCTOR -------------------------------------------------   
   Node(char c, int f) {
      ch = c;
      freq = f;
   }

// METHODS -----------------------------------------------------
   public void displayNode(){
      System.out.print(ch + "" + freq);
   }
   
}  // end class Node
```

PQ.java

```
public class PQ {

// FIELDS ------------------------------------------------------
   private int maxSize;
   private Tree[] queArray;
   private int nItems;

// CONSTRUCTOR -------------------------------------------------  
   public PQ(int s){
      maxSize = s;
      queArray = new Tree[maxSize];
      nItems = 0;
    }

// METHODS -----------------------------------------------------
   public void insert(Tree item){
     
      int j;

      // insertion of first item
      if(nItems==0)                         
         queArray[nItems++] = item;         
      
      else {
         for(j=nItems-1; j>=0; j--) {
            if( item.root.freq > queArray[j].root.freq )
               queArray[j+1] = queArray[j]; 
            else                           
               break;                     
         }  // end for
         queArray[j+1] = item;              // insert it
         nItems++;
       }  // end else (nItems > 0)
    }  // end insert()
//-------------------------------------------------------------
   public Tree remove(){
      return queArray[--nItems];
   }
//-------------------------------------------------------------
   public Tree peekMin(){
      return queArray[nItems-1];
   }
//-------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean isEmpty(){
      return (nItems==0);
   }
//-------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean isFull(){
      return (nItems == maxSize);
   }
//-------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getSize(){
      return nItems;
   }

}  // end class PQ
```

Tree.java

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Tree {
    
// FIELDS ------------------------------------------------------
    
   public Node root;              // first node of tree

// CONSTRUCTOR -------------------------------------------------
   public Tree(Node nd){
      root = nd;
   }              // root of tree from argument
   
// METHODS -----------------------------------------------------
   public int getFreq(){
      return root.freq;
   }

   public void display(){
      Stack<Node> globalStack = new Stack<Node>();
      globalStack.push(root);
      
      // IF YOUR TREE ISN'T DISPLAYING CORRECTLY,
      // ADJUST THIS VARIABLE (INCREASE IT)
      int adjustMeToFixDisplay = 4;
      
      int nBlanks = adjustMeToFixDisplay*getDepth(root);
      boolean isRowEmpty = false;
     
      while(isRowEmpty==false) {
         Stack<Node> localStack = new Stack<Node>();
         isRowEmpty = true;

         for(int j=0; j<nBlanks; j++)
            System.out.print(' ');

         while(globalStack.isEmpty()==false) {
            Node temp = (Node)globalStack.pop();
            if(temp != null) {
               temp.displayNode();
               localStack.push(temp.leftChild);
               localStack.push(temp.rightChild);

               if(temp.leftChild != null ||
                                   temp.rightChild != null)
                  isRowEmpty = false;
            }
            
            else {
               System.out.print("--");
               localStack.push(null);
               localStack.push(null);
            }
            
            for(int j=0; j<nBlanks*2-2; j++)
               System.out.print(' ');
          }  // end while globalStack not empty
         
         System.out.println();
         nBlanks /= 2;
         while(localStack.isEmpty()==false)
            globalStack.push( localStack.pop() );
         
      }  // end while isRowEmpty is false
   }  // end displayTree()
   
   // returns depth of tree to help make tree display correctly
   public int getDepth(Node node) {
       if (node == null)
           return 0;
       return 1 + getDepth(node.leftChild) + getDepth(node.rightChild);
   }

}  // end class T
```

Comment: Placing `codedMsg = codedMsg + codeTable[index];` outside of your for-loop means it will only get executed once.  Though I don’t think that’s the cause of your problem.

Comment: You are correct, so after spending some more time it seems to me that the code I wrote in method ```makeCodeTable``` is the cause of my problem. But I don't know what I am exactly doing wrong since I know I have to subtract 64 to get the index value.

Comment: `I have to subtract 64` - why would you do that, why not allow for any char value in the range 0-255 to be en- or decoded directly? That also does away with any special handling of space, line feed, and so on.